# Accessing web service JSON from cucumber/gherkin

Tags: objective-c, testing, cucumber, gherkin

I am using cucumber to perform integration test for an iOS app written in Objective C. I want to access JSON values from a web service call inside the app and confirm it elsewhere. From what I have seen it is possible to use something like:
*"When the client requests GET /fruits"*
to get the JSON. Where in Objective C do I name the web service call "fruits"? I have no problems accessing all the labels with accessibility identifier, but I guess there is a different method to address the web service calls.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are testing in process, you should have mocked the rest service. You will call the mock and get whatever is in there. If  you are testing out of process, you need a client that is compatible with (I assume) objective C, from which you would call something like "http://localhost:[port you are running on]/fruits"

Comment: Yes, I am testing the app in process. I just don´t understand how I can access the JSON from the web service within the gherkin feature file.

Comment: You don't access in the feature file. The step definitions do the work of getting the data from the mock of the webservice. I guess you can call the webservice if you create a ObjC client in your test framework.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your time.